Rigorous Mathematical foundations of Machine Learning / Deep Learning / Neural Networks
I am an Engineering Graduate (with a strong background in Probability/Measure Theory, Linear Algebra and Calculus) wanting to dig deep into Deep Learning and Neural Networks, and I'm looking for mathematically thorough and rigurous (almost pedantic) material and books to go through the material, but I don't seem to find something of my liking among all the myriad of hype-train books out there considering how popular Machine Learning has become in the last years. Even the rather non-hands-on books about it seem to be too hands-on to me.
I have both Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop, which I started working through (about 150 Pages), as well as Deep Learning by Goodfellow (which I only skimmed through), but I am not happy with either. They both seem to try to cover too much material, with little rigorousness and detail, getting lost in specificalities. I am only speaking out of intuition here, but I feel like due to the assumption that the average reader lacks real depth in the areas of Probability, Linear Algebra and Calculus (which is clear by the sloppiness of the use of them), I feel like there's the need for too much explanation.
What I'm looking for is a more concise, but more mathematically precise book on the fundamentals of Deep Learning / Machine Learning that assumes a strong and formal knowledge of Linear Algebra, Probability Theory (Kolmogorov, Probability Spaces, etc.), and Calculus where I can draw my own (mathematical) conclusions and without too much specific gibberish (e.g. I don't need 5 examples, graphs and intuitive explanations on the difference between bias and variance, I just need a rigorous definition of both, and a few important Theorems around them which I can work with).
My reasoning here is that the field is so complex already and expanding in an exponential manner on so many directions, and understanding concepts like regularization and optimization seems so daunting, because of the lack of mathematical abstractions behind it, so it seems that every application needs its own interpretation. As experience has showed me, this happens when there's a lack of fundamental mathematical knowledge that can help extrapolate into other examples without the explicit need to understand the details of it.
An analogous example is say with systems of differential equations: You might need to understand a few examples (e.g. Romeo and Juliet/Love affairs https://ai.stanford.edu/~rajatr/articles/SS_love_dEq.pdf) but then it suffices to be able to understand those systems as general mathematical constructs and how to solve them/approach them without having to understand intuitively every single example a priori.
Thank you

The math behind deep learning isn’t very deep. I wonder if you’d like to glance at my notes on logistic regression, mainly section 8. Deep learning isn’t much more complicated than that, except that the prediction function gets fancier.

Do you know of this?

ML kind of thinks in Pytorch. Most machine learning researchers are not mathematicians. Measure theory wont tell you much about ML. Neural networks are so big that it becomes mathematically intractable past essentially 2 layers. You can't sit down and grind out a book to learn ML like you can to learn analysis.

Hi: These comments to the OP are all quite insightful and full of wisdom. One thing I feel should be added is that the OP used the term "neural networks and deep learning" in the question so I'm not sure if the recommendation of "machine learning" books will be specific enough  to the OP ?  I think of neural networks ( I'm not familiar with deep learning nearly as much )  as one specific subset of machine learning but I guess different books can approach things differently. Also, a book by  Prince is a deep learning text has gotten good reviews. I'll send a link in a follow up comment.

I have not read the text nor do I know much ( close to zero ) about deep learning. Like the OP, I've been keeping my eyes out for a good text. I haven't bought it but this book has been getting some positive feedback. Unfortunately, I can't recall where I read about the positive feedback but it was multiple places. https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Deep-Learning-Simon-Prince/dp/0262048647/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1FJST5

I read the original post again and the term "machine learning" is in the question title but not in the body. So, that's my mistake and anyone who recommended machine learning books was not pointing the OP in the wrong direction. My apologies to those people.

Don't know if you will find this interesting but it might be worthwhile giving Kevin Murphy's book(s) on probabilistic machine learning a try.
https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html

For the general theory of machine learning,  Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David's book Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms is pretty rigorous in my opinion. (Advanced intro to ML course at Carnegie Mellon University uses this as the reference.) However, it only covers a little bit about deep learning near the end of the book.
For deep learning, I am not sure if there is a universally accepted mathematical framework. Notes provided in the other answer looks pretty nice.
I personally had experience with a book by Daniel Roberts, Sho Yaida, Boris Hanin The Principles of Deep Learning Theory which formulates a theory of Deep Neural Networks in the language of effective field theory from theoretical physics involving path integrals, renormalization, etc (I only came across this due to my own background).
It is as rigorous as physicists do quantum field theory; however, whether the framework is widely accepted is up to debate, and it might not be an easy read for people without background in theoretical physics.

These notes on DL theory by Matus Telgarsky are very good.

You can try books on information geometry. It's my personal "speculation" that information geometry will become prominent in a decade. Mainstream ML/DL/AI don't have a widely accepted rigorous foundation; the closest that one can get seems to be the theory of probably approximately correct (PAC) learning. Many ML/DL/AI researchers never even studied mathematical analysis at the undergraduate level, let alone differential geometry or measure theory. The situation is much like physics: rigor is not there, foundation is not there, nor do they care.

While this answer has a cynical flavor, it corroborates what I've seen as well.
